# Making bars longer and replacing rests in Sibelius

Tags: chords, sibelius

1) I am using Sibelius version 7.5. My first aim is to transform every 4/4's bar into a 4/2's bar with a whole note rest at the end of every measure in the score.

[image]

2) My second aim is to replace every whole rest (at the end of every measure) with quarter notes from the other Sibelius file, which is called "Modal Functions"

[image]

3) The mistake that i get when i select bars 1-16 (home–> select bars–> end of score) and change time signature from 4/4's to 4/2's (notations–> time signature) is that all the notes end up in one bar, since i specifically only aim to change the key signature (of every 4/4's bar) to 4/2's and to leave a whole rest after the first four quarter notes in every measure.

After that i am unclear about what goes after the process of changing time signatures while later inputting quarter notes from the other Sibelius file into the 4/2's measure endings (whole rests).

***Postscript: i don't want to take the time to do it by hand (on bar after another bar) for the reason that it consumes time and i have a lot of other Sibelius files unsorted.***

Also, it wouldn't matter for me if the chord symbol above the staff does not copy itself.

An easier method below suggested would be very appreciating.

Comment: Another postscript: The third photo i could not upload, for the reason that i don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: I suggest asking this on the Sibelius forum http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3. There are people there who have used Sibelius professionally for years, and who will probably never see this question on SE.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this bar-by bar, but it won't be as laborious as you might fear.

No need to create the empty bars first.  Open both scores alongside each other.  System-select a bar from the second score.  Ctrl-C to Copy it.  Paste it into the appropriate position in the first score.  As it's a System selection it will be inserted rather than replacing the existing bar.

Once you get into the rhythm, this will be very fast.